# Netmask validation seems not working using regex in bash script while ip validation working fine

Tags: regex, linux, bash, validation

I wrote simple script to validate IP address and Netmask as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

validFormatIP()
{
    echo $1 | grep -w -E -o '^(25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Valid ipaddress"
    else
        echo "Inalid ipaddress"
    fi
}

validNetMask()
{
    echo $1 | grep -w -E -o '^(254|252|248|240|224|192|128)\\.0\\.0\\.0|255\\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)\\.0\\.0|255\\.255\\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)\\.0|255\\.255\\.255\\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Valid netmask"
    else
        echo "Invalid netmask"
    fi  
}

setIpAddress()
{
    ip_address=`echo $1 | awk -F= '{print $2}'` 
    validFormatIP $ip_address
}
setNetMask()
{
    ip_address=`echo $1 | awk -F= '{print $2}'` 
    validNetMask $ip_address
}

let "n_count=0"
netmask=""

let "i_count=0"
ipaddess=""

while getopts ":i:n:" OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
        n)
            netmask="Netmask=$OPTARG"
            let "n_count+=1"
            ;;
        i)
            ipaddess="IpAddess=$OPTARG"
            let "i_count+=1"
            ;;

        ?)  
            echo "wrong command syntax"
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ $i_count -eq 1 ]
then
    setIpAddress $ipaddess
    exit 0
fi

if [ $n_count -eq 1 ]
then
    setNetMask $netmask
    exit 0
fi
```

Using above result i have successfully filter out invalid IPaddress but not able to filter invalid netmask.I have run above script with different argument as follows and see the output also below after script executing

```
$ ./script.bash -i 192.168.0.1
Valid ipaddress

$./script.bash -i 255.255.0.0
Inalid ipaddress

$./script.bash -n 255.255.255.0
Invalid netmask
```

As you see above output the result for IP address validation is expected but why it reject the netmask even i enter valid netmask `` `255.255.255.0 `` ?

Any one have idea what i miss in netmask validation or something wrong in my script?

Comment: good..can you explain expressions between '' ? thank you

Comment: you mean `?` right? or something else?

Comment: i think `^` means beginning of ip addr, `|` means OR, but don't know what it does... and `?` as well...also 25[0-4]...thank you

Comment: i think 25[0-4] means 250-251-252-253-254

Comment: @MortezaLSC yes correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep` doesn't double escaping dots etc so this will work:

```
validNetMask() {
   echo $1 | grep -w -E -o '^(254|252|248|240|224|192|128)\.0\.0\.0|255\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)\.0\.0|255\.255\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)\.0|255\.255\.255\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)' > /dev/null
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "Valid netmask"
   else
      echo "Invalid netmask"
   fi
}
```

Better to use this concise version:

```
validNetMask() {
   grep -E -q '^(254|252|248|240|224|192|128)\.0\.0\.0|255\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)\.0\.0|255\.255\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)\.0|255\.255\.255\.(254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)' <<< "$1" && echo "Valid netmask" || echo "Invalid netmask"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mine:

```
validate_netmask () {
    n_masks=(${1//./ })
    [ "${#n_masks[@]}" -ne 4 ] && return 1
    for i in ${1//./ }; do
        bits=$(echo "obase=2;ibase=10;$i" | bc)
        pre=$((8-${#bits}))
        if [ "$bits" = 0 ]; then
            zeros=00000000
        elif [ "$pre" -gt 0 ]; then
            zeros=$(for ((i=1;i<=$pre;i++)); do echo -n 0; done)
        fi
        b_mask=$b_mask$zeros$bits
            unset zeros
    done
    if [ $b_mask = ${b_mask%%0*}${b_mask##*1} ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```